# Override ISC DHCP's `option routers` with the absence of that option?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I was thinking I'd rather not assign my TV a default gateway, and since I use ISC DHCP 4.4 I tried to override the general subnet configuration with a host specific configuration, like this:

```
host Samsung-TV {
        hardware ethernet aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff;
        option routers;
}
```

Not too surprisingly this was a configuration error. The below config works, but is technically assigning a gateway:

```
host Samsung-TV {
        hardware ethernet aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff;
        option routers 0.0.0.0;
}
```

Is there any way to override `option routers` with the actual *absence* of that option? Or is that a useless technicality that shouldn't matter?

Comment: why don't you give localhost as router address, i.e. option routers 127.0.0.1; this option can also be checked, option router-discovery false;

Comment: @StephenHarris Good find. Minus points for not finding it myself.